# Concatenate or join multiple tables to a single table in CodeIgniter 3 without omitting rows if there is an empty cell

Tags: sql, codeigniter-3

Assume I have 4 different tables 'user', 'favorite_book', 'books', 'user_image'. The data in the tables as below,

user:

```
|user_id |name|contact |dateCreated|
|--------|----_|-------|-----------|
|1       |Ani  | 9999  | 1232142   |
|2       |Aslam| 8888  | 1234563   |
|3       |Jhon | 7777  |2425325    |
|4       |Keras| 6666  |535345     |
|5       |Sudi | 5555  |453454     |
```

favorite_book:

```
|user_id|book_id|dateCreated|
|-------|-------|-----------|
|1      | xys   |           |
|3      | sdf   |           |
|4      | 7rlm  |           |
|5      | 7rlm  |           |
```

note: here 'user_id' 2 dose not have any favorite_book.

books

```
|book_id|book_name|book_author|dateCreated|
|-------|---------|-----------|-----------|
|xys    |book_1   | auth_1    | 
|7rlm   |book_3   | auth_3    |
|sdf    |book_9   | auth_9    |
|rtyu   | book_1  | auth_1    |
```

user_image

```
|user_id| img     |dateCreated|
|--     |---------|-----------|
|1      |Ani.png  |           |
|2      |Aslam.png|           |
|3      |NULL     |           |
|4      |NULL     |           |
|5      |Sudi.png |           |
```

note: few users did not provide user_image which is marked as NULL

expected solution:
I need to create a table which combine all the tables to get detailed information of user at a glance. The expected solution is as follows.

```
|user_id|name |contact|img      |book_name|dateCreated|
|-------|-----|-------|---------|---------|-----------|
|1      |Ani  | 9999  | Ani.png |book_1   |1232142    |
|2      |Aslam| 8888  |Aslam.png||1234563 |           |
|3      |Jhon |  7777 |         |book_9   |2425325    |
|4      |Keras| 6666  |         |book_3   |535345     |
|5      |Sudi | 5555  |Sudi.png |book_3   |4534543    |
```

note: dateCreated is from 'user' table.

I created the table by combining all the tables with help of  $this->db->join(), however it omits the rows if there is an empty or null cell.  I would like to get a table with all available information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that would be like this :

```
SELECT
    u.user_id
    , name
    , contact
    , img
    , book_name
    , u.dateCreated
FROM
    users                   u
    JOIN user_image         ui
        ON u.user_id = ui.user_id
    LEFT JOIN favorite_book fb
        ON u.user_id = fb.user_id
    LEFT JOIN books         b
        ON bf.book_id = b.book_id;
  on bf.book_id = b.book_id
```

Comment: it works, that is really helpful as I am a beginner. What is the difference between, say, `LEFT JOIN favorite_book fb  ON u.user_id = fb.user_id` and `RIGHT JOIN favorite_book ON  fb.user_id  = u.user_id` ?

Comment: Read (Microsoft documents)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15] about all kind of joins and their difference